# VBA Converting to proper case skipping certain words

Tags: vba, excel

Currently I am able to convert a range of cells to proper case. I need to skip certain words in a cell while converting to proper case.

example: "**get of from here**" will be converted to "**Get Of From Here**"

But the word "**Of**" should not convert to proper case.
can it be done?

Here is the code which I have written to convert the range into proper case.

```
Sub Processproper()

Dim Rng As Range

Dim WorkRng As Range

Dim xTitleId

On Error Resume Next

xTitleId = "SelectRange"

Set WorkRng = Application.Selection

Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Select Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)

For Each Rng In WorkRng

If IsEmpty(Rng) = True Then

Else
    Rng.Value = StrConv(Rng.Value, vbProperCase)

End If

Next

end sub
```

Comment: a quick search gave me this: http://excelribbon.tips.net/T010560_Making_PROPER_Skip_Certain_Words.html

Comment: thank you Scott Craner i got the function from the link that you suggested, however how to call it in my macro, can you please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub Processproper()

    Dim Rng As Range

    Dim WorkRng As Range

    Dim xTitleId

    On Error Resume Next

    xTitleId = "SelectRange"

    Set WorkRng = Application.Selection

    Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Select Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)

    For Each Rng In WorkRng

    If IsEmpty(Rng) = True Then

    Else
        Rng.Value = Title(Rng)

    End If

    Next

End Sub


Function Title(ByVal ref As Range) As String
    Dim vaArray As Variant
    Dim c As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim J As Integer
    Dim vaLCase As Variant
    Dim str As String

    ' Array contains terms that should be lower case
    vaLCase = Array("a", "an", "and", "in", "is", _
      "of", "or", "the", "to", "with")

    c = StrConv(ref, 3)
    'split the words into an array
    vaArray = Split(c, " ")
    For i = (LBound(vaArray) + 1) To UBound(vaArray)
        For J = LBound(vaLCase) To UBound(vaLCase)
            ' compare each word in the cell against the
            ' list of words to remain lowercase. If the
            ' Upper versions match then replace the
            ' cell word with the lowercase version.
            If UCase(vaArray(i)) = UCase(vaLCase(J)) Then
                vaArray(i) = vaLCase(J)
            End If
        Next J
    Next i

  ' rebuild the sentence
    str = ""
    For i = LBound(vaArray) To UBound(vaArray)
        str = str & " " & vaArray(i)
    Next i

    Title = Trim(str)
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks a lot,,,,,this really made my day. :)))))))))

Comment: @tharun did you hit the check mark in my answer to mark it as the right answer?